# Where should I store functions that print combined strings from model data?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a ProductsController and Product model. A Product has the following fields:

- id
- parent_id
- name
- quantity
- (more fields that aren't relevant to the question)

Products can be children of other products. This allows a product to essentially inherit properties of a parent product (name, photos, weight, etc).

It's simple enough to print the name of a product in my templates:

```
{{ $product->name }}
```

However, I also want to do the following in many (but not all) cases:

- Use the parent products name if the child product name is empty
- Append (Pack of 'n') when quantity > 1

Since I'm using this often in my code, rather than writing if/else statements in my blade template, I've added the following function to my Product model.

```
public function getNameAndQuantity()
{
    // Use the parent products name if this child product has no name
    if(empty($this->name))
    {
        $this->name = $this->parent->name;
    }

    // Append quantity if empty
    if($this->quantity > 1)
    {
        return $this->name . ' (Pack of ' . $this->quantity . ')';
    }

    return $this->name;
}
```

This works as expected. **My question is: where should this function go? It doesn't seem like it belongs in the Product model.**

I've read a bit about creating libraries for this kind of functionality, but I'm a bit lost on naming conventions, or best practices for hooking things up so the code stays readable. Or maybe this belongs in a template partial instead...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Laravel, I would suggest to this in Controller itself.

But this depends on preferences, in my case, I would create a Helper class and then create a facade for it, finally use it via service providers.

For achieving this correct steps would be:

1. Create folders in `app/` named `helpers`, `facades`, `services`
2. Register them all in `ClassLoader` it stays at `app/start/global.php` and in `composer.json` autoload
3. Further create a helper class with functions you need in `helpers`, then create a facades based on [information here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades)
4. Now create a service provider in `app/services` based on [information here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#service-providers) and register it in service providers in `app/config/app.php`

Run and you will have static facades to access all these functions easily.

Comment: Thanks @apsdehal, I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I agree that this probably doesn't belong directly in the controller. Appreciate all the helpful links :)